# How to control the frame rate of my LWJGL window int LWJGL3?

Tags: java, lwjgl, frame-rate

I'm learning now `LWJGL3`, and I have a problem.
I want to limit the frame rate of my window to 60 FPS, but I don't know how to do that in `LWJGL3`.
In `LWJGL2` which I used before I switched to `LWJGL3` I call `Display.sync(60);` before calling `Display.update();`, but in `LWJGL3` the `Display` class was replaced by window which controlled by the `GLFW` class.
SO, which method replaced the `Display.sync(int frame_rate);` method?

Comment: It would be best  to run your game at a fixed fps rather than limit it. [Fix your timestep](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/)

Comment: But I want my game won't use a lot of computer resources, but try to save CPU and GPU.

Comment: Please post it as answer, so I can tick this answer for who search for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable V-sync with `glSwapInterval(1);` after you create your window which will limit the fps to your monitor's refresh rate.